# clear the old value from textbox when the form in design view mode

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am using access 2010
I have a text box in access form
When I enter a value into the text box in view mode then open the form in design view mode then go to view mode again, I found the same Old value i was entered before.

Comment: Is this the Bound Form? If so the behavior is normal.

Comment: yes
Thank you thank you  PaulFrancis